# Equalizer for Creative Sound Blaster Audigy FX?

Tags: drivers, sound

I am very new to linux and I had a question about my soundcard. I have a Creative Sound Blaster Audigy FX, which I really love and have been using for years. I decided I wanted to make the switch to linux, but I have run into a problem. The card works, I can hear sound coming out of my headphones, but I haven't been able to find linux drivers that will give me the Sound Blaster Control Panel, which, most importantly, has a equalizer. I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, The Audigy FX is an HDA card, and uses an ALC898 chip from Realtek. Is there some other application that I can use instead if no linux version of the control panel exists? This is a real dealbreaker for me, as I am a bit of an audiophile, and I have gotten very used to the sound of my headphones+card. I appreciate any help.

Comment: You haven't provided anything specific to this site, as this is a Ubuntu user support site, not a generic GNU/Linux support site. Also the linux kernel modules (or drivers) are based not on brand/model of card, but on chipset make/model, and Creative usually made cards using components made by outside suppliers, so you need to more specific and tell us what OS/release you are using (so we know software stack) & chipset used by the card (which can vary for popular cards with long supported lives due to changes in components)

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, The Audigy FX is an HDA card, and uses an ALC898 chip from Realtek. I apologize, I am new to this.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at easyeffects (https://github.com/wwmm/easyeffects).

It should be available via repos or software center.

An Equalizer is provided as well as many other enhancers/effects.

Answer (score 0):

For audiophiles, the best option so far is EasyEffects / PulseEffects. However, setting it up is not easy and you will need help to unlock the potential of your equipment. Try using my presets: [EasyPulse](https://github.com/p-chan5/EasyPulse) They might help a bit.